# LinkedList removeLastOccurrence

Tags: java, java-8, doubly-linked-list

I am new to computer science, so forgive my ignorance.  For the [`LinkedList` that is in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/LinkedList.html),
does the `removeLastOccurrence` method use the `equals` method between the object passed in or does it simply compare the memory location?

Comment: Read the [spec of `LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeLastOccurrence-java.lang.Object-).  It directs you to [spec of `Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#removeLastOccurrence-java.lang.Object-), which tells you exactly what this method does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/LinkedList.java, the source for that method is:

```
public boolean removeLastOccurrence(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev) {
            if (x.item == null) {
                unlink(x);
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (Node<E> x = last; x != null; x = x.prev) {
            if (o.equals(x.item)) {
                unlink(x);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thus if the object you want to remove is `null`, then it looks for a `null` value in the list. If the object is not `null`, then it uses the `equals` method. However, keep in mind that unless `equals` is specifically overridden to implement value equality, it will default to identity equality (that is, by comparing memory addresses like `==` does for objects)